# Как записать в state значение инлайн кнопки?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

**Есть два хендлера обрабатывающие две инлайн кнопки. Мне нужно чтобы хендлер был один и стейт в хендлере принимал значение конкретно нажатой кнопки. Например при нажатии на кнопку "Мужской" вызывался хендлер, помещающий в стейт значение "Мужской". Тоже самое с женским, хендлер один и тот же но значение передает уже "Женский"**

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text='button_2', state=Form.gender)
async def callback_btn2(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    await state.update_data(gender="Женский")
    await tell_info(callback_query, state)


@dp.callback_query_handler(text='button_1', state=Form.gender)
async def callback_btn1(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    print(callback_query)
    await state.update_data(gender="Мужской")
    await tell_info(callback_query, state)


async def set_gender(update: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery]):
    btn1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Мужской', callback_data='button_1')
    btn2 = InlineKeyboardButton('Женский', callback_data='button_2')
    kb1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(btn1, btn2)
    await bot.send_message(update.from_user.id, "Прекрасно! Какого вы пола?", reply_markup=kb1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто сделайте префикс перед данными `prefix:data` и этот префикс и фильтруйте.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_startswith='gender_but:', state=Form.gender)
async def callback_btn2(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    # Делайте
    await callback_query.answer()
    # вместо await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id)
    dict_genders = {"male": "Мужской", "female": "Женский"}
    await state.update_data(gender=dict_genders[callback_query.data.split(":")[1]])
    await tell_info(callback_query, state)


async def set_gender(update: Union[types.Message, types.CallbackQuery]):
    btn1 = InlineKeyboardButton('Мужской', callback_data='gender_but:male')
    btn2 = InlineKeyboardButton('Женский', callback_data='gender_but:female')
    kb1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup().row(btn1, btn2)
    await bot.send_message(update.from_user.id, "Прекрасно! Какого вы пола?", reply_markup=kb1)
```

Comment: Спасибо, интересное решение. Даже в чате аио не ответили